# Reading all files in all directories

Tags: python, file, file-handling, directory-structure

I have the code working to read in the values of a single text file but am having difficulties reading all files from all directories and putting all of the contents together.

Here is what I have:

```
filename = '*'
filesuffix = '*'
location = os.path.join('Test', filename + "." + filesuffix)
Document = filename
thedictionary = {}
with open(location) as f:
 file_contents = f.read().lower().split(' ') # split line on spaces to make a list
 for position, item in enumerate(file_contents): 
     if item in thedictionary:
      thedictionary[item].append(position)
     else:
      thedictionary[item] = [position]
wordlist = (thedictionary, Document)
#print wordlist
#print thedictionary
```

note that I am trying to stick the wildcard * in for the filename as well as the wildcard for the filesuffix. I get the following error:

"IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Test/*.*'"

I am not sure if this is even the right way to do it but it seems that if I somehow get the wildcards working - it should work.

I have gotten this example to work:  [Python - reading files from directory file not found in subdirectory (which is there)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580716/python-reading-files-from-directory-file-not-found-in-subdirectory-which-is-t)

Which is a little different - but don't know how to update it to read all files. I am thinking that in this initial set of code:

```
previous_dir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir('testfilefolder')
#add something here?
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
```

That I would need to add something where I have an outer for loop but don't quite know what to put in it..

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Python doesn't support wildcards directly in filenames to the `open()` call. You'll need to use the [`glob` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) instead to load files from a single level of subdirectories, or use [`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) to walk an arbitrary directory structure.

Opening all text files in all subdirectories, one level deep:

```
import glob

for filename in glob.iglob(os.path.join('Test', '*', '*.txt')):
    with open(filename) as f:
        # one file open, handle it, next loop will present you with a new file.
```

Opening all text files in an arbitrary nesting of directories:

```
import os
import fnmatch

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk('Test'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.txt'):
        with open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)):
            # one file open, handle it, next loop will present you with a new file.
```

Comment: Thank you Martijn for that.  I will try it out and see what happens.  I am curious though to as why they make two different functions glob and the os.walk.  On a little reading I do see that glob will let you use wildcards, but os.walk will not - instead you need to filter the results.  I don't understand what is really going on as when I am thinking filter the results I thought that is what wildcard expressions did.  I found this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931099/quicker-to-os-walk-or-glob

If you have any insight and time, any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: `glob()` does not support arbitrary nested subdirectories (yet). That's the only difference here. `os.walk()` does but requires more filtering. Note that `glob()` uses the *same filter method* (the `fnmatch` module) already in it's own implementation.